# I moved my starling project now i keep getting context is missing errors :/ any solutions?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework

Flash Builder 4.7 kept having silent crashes so i deleted the workspace folder and moved my project to another directory. Now i keep getting context is missing.. errors.

It's a starling project with starling 1.6 . Just to be clear it worked perfectly before i had to move it :/

I reloaded the libraries i used but cant get it to work.

When i publish a release build the projects works fine but i can't debug it.

```
Error: Starling context is missing
at starling.textures::Texture$/empty()[C:\Users\Jørgen\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\PrimaVistaRunner\frameworks\starling\src\starling\textures\Texture.as:346]
at starling.textures::Texture$/fromBitmapData()[C:\Users\Jørgen\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\PrimaVistaRunner\frameworks\starling\src\starling\textures\Texture.as:251]
at starling.textures::Texture$/fromBitmap()[C:\Users\Jørgen\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\PrimaVistaRunner\frameworks\starling\src\starling\textures\Texture.as:227]
at Assets$/getTexture()[C:\Users\Jørgen\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\PrimaVistaRunner\src\Assets.as:105]
at staffObjects::WholeNote$cinit()[C:\Users\Jørgen\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\PrimaVistaRunner\src\staffObjects\WholeNote.as:11]
at global$init()
```

I'm fairly new to programming so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add event handler to `Event.CONTEXT3D_CREATE` or `Event.ROOT_CREATED` event before `_starling.start`:

```
_starling.addEventListener(starling.events.Event.ROOT_CREATED, rootCreated);
...
private function rootCreated(e:Event):void
{
    _starling.removeEventListener(starling.events.Event.ROOT_CREATED, rootCreated);
    _starling.start();
}
```

Comment: Tried it but didnt work :/
http://i.imgur.com/yG1YuT6.png?1
I noticed the starling package folder was white. Doesn't that mean its empty ?(it issnt)

Comment: Try to use [starling.swc](https://github.com/Gamua/Starling-Framework/blob/master/starling/bin/starling.swc?raw=true) file instead of raw sources.

Comment: When i use the swc i get
Starling.textures::Texture$/empty
source not found.

Comment: Try to write `new Assets();` in the constructor of the Main class. And check paths to the embedded images.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jorgen i hope this link might have the answers for your problem.
http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/handling-lost-context